# Jquery mmenu Navbars fixed height change?

Tags: jquery, css, mmenu

Before I start modifying any code, I was wondering if anyone knew why the navbars height is fixed at 40px and limited to 4 at the top?

Also does anyone know of any issues I may run into by making this taller or dynamic?

Comment: Why not paste an example, a small snippet..

Comment: Limited to 4 whats at the top? Four menu items? Four pixels?